# How to simplify this Boolean expression furthermore

Tags: boolean-algebra

Variables are $E, B, S, V_1, V_2, V_3$

Here is the Boolean expression that I need to simplify

$$EB'SV_1'V_2'V_3 + EB'SV_1'V_2V_3 + EB'SV_1V_2'V_3 + EB'SV_1V_2V_3' + EB'SV_1V_2V_3$$

And this is how I simplified,

$$\begin{align}
&EB'SV_1'V_2'V_3 + EB'SV_1'V_2V_3 + EB'SV_1V_2'V_3 + EB'SV_1V_2V_3' + EB'SV_1V_2V_3 \\
&EB'S(V_1'V_2'V_3 + V_1'V_2V_3 + V_1V_2'V_3 + V_1V_2V_3' + V_1V_2V_3) \\
&EB'S[V_2'V_3(V_1 + V_1') + V_2V_3(V_1 + V_1') + V_1V_2V_3'] \\
&V_1 + V_1' = 1
\end{align}$$

So,

$$\begin{align}
&EB'S[V_2'V_3 + V_2V_3 + V_1V_2V_3'] \\
&EB'S[V_3(V_2 + V_2') + V_1V_2V_3'] \\
&V_2 + V_2' = 1
\end{align}$$

So,

$$EB'S(V_3 + V_1V_2V_3')$$

But when I solve this equation through a simulator, it gives me the simplified expression as

$$EB'S(V_3 + V_1V_2)$$

Can anyone tell me where did I do wrong?

Comment: Please use mathjax! `$V_1$` gives $V_1;$ better: avoid the subscripts and use $P,Q,R$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done nothing wrong, you just didn't see an opportunity to simplify a bit.
The two expressions within parentheses are actually equivalent:

$$\begin{align}
V_3 + V_1V_2 &= V_3 + V_1V_2(1) \\
&= V_3 + V_1V_2(V_3 + V_3') \\
&= (1)V_3 + V_1V_2V_3 + V_1V_2V_3' \\
&= (1 + V_1V_2)V_3 + V_1V_2V_3' \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} (1)V_3 + V_1V_2V_3' \quad\\
&=V_3 + V_1V_2V_3'
\end{align}$$

$(*)$ note that this step is sort of unique to Boolean algebra and not too obvious